# How to determine if the SHIFT or CTRL key was pressed when launching the application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010, shift, ctrl

I need to be able to determine if the SHIFT or CTRL keys were pressed **when the application is launched**

How can I do this for a Windows Forms Application?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. The following will return `True` or `False` depending on whether the key is pressed

```
My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown
My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown
```

**Example**

```
    If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Or My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
        MsgBox("SHIFT or CTRL key down")
    End If
```

If you are asking about event handling, `KeyEventArgs Class` is needed. **[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx#)** you can view some examples how to detect shift/ctrl keypress

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding the above code in the Form_Load event of the start-up form enables me to achieve this.

Answer (score 7):

Alternative solution using [Control.ModifierKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Or Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
        MsgBox("SHIFT or CTRL key pressed.")
    End If
```